# Extract strings between two words

Tags: ruby, regex

- From this string:

  ```
  "Patient Gia Gottlieb's encounter with Dr. Madge Bahringer"
  ```

  I need to extract the patient name `Gia Gottlieb` between the words `Patient` and `Dr.` and the doctor name `Madge Bahringer` after the word `Dr.`.
- From this string:

  ```
  "Service Check 14 - cost $2271.00"
  ```

  I need to extract the service name `Check 14` and cost `2271.00`.

Help please.

Comment: Very very tough to do so.. need some references..

Comment: hi, thanks for responding. what do you mean? do you need more info?

Comment: Yes..ofcourse.. How from a piles of strings, I will get out 2 words ? If there is no logic.

Comment: The words between `Patient` and `Dr.` are not `Gia Gottlieb` but `Gia Gottlieb's encounter with`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a fixed template, you can simply replace the blanks with catch-alls:

```
s.scan /Patient (.+)\'s encounter with (.+)/
# => [["Gia Gottlieb", "Dr. Madge Bahringer"]]
```

and the same way:

```
s2.scan /Service (.+) - cost \$(.+)/
# => [["Check 14", "2271.00"]]
```